# Getting value of the selected items php mysql html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have here a sample where i get the data of the first dropdown

My problem is if i choose the selected item how will i get or store the value of the first dropdown because i need it on the query on my next dropdown. i need to automatically get the value if i choose something

```
<select name="o_id " id="o_id" class="custom-select" >
    <?php
        $hall_qry = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `office_hall`   order by `office_name` asc");
        while($row = $hall_qry->fetch_assoc()): 
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['o_id'] ?>">
                <?php echo $row['office_name']?>
            </option>
        <?php
        endwhile; 
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<select class ="custom-select" name="" id="">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you need to perform another `SELECT` statement on the database to populate the second dropdown based on the selected value of the first dropdown? When the first dropdown changes, you would need to use JavaScript the grab the selected value and perform an AJAX call to execute the second `SELECT` statement asynchronously in order to populate the second dropdown without reloading the page.

Comment: This seems like something that would be better accomplished using JavaScript along with ajax requests. I would recommend looking into that.

Comment: perfectly doable without ajax. just submit the form, get the first select's value and use it to populate the second